# How to inject mocked dependencies into struts actions from StrutsTeseCase?

Tags: junit, struts2, mocking, mockito

I am writing a test case extending from strutsspringtestcase and invoking the actions as below:

Here is the Login Action

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport
{
    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("DependencyClass")
    protected DependencyClass dependencyObject;

    public void execute()
    {
    return dependencyObject.method1();
    }
}
```

Also, I am creating mocked objects using mockito as below:

```
   public class LoginActionTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase
   {
    @Mock
    DepenencyClass mockedObject;

    @InjectMocks
    LoginAction loginAction;

    @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception{
     super.setUp();
     when(mockedObject.Method1()).thenReturn(result);
    }

    public void testLoginAction throws Exception{ 
    `ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/login");
     LoginAction action = (LoginAction) proxy.getAction();
     String result = proxy.execute();`
    }

}
```

My expectation is that the action should hit mocked method instead of the original method. There is certainly a gap in achieving this but any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Post some code where you have problems.

Comment: Create mock objects and use some test context with mock-s in your tests.

Comment: I created mocks using for the dependent classes in Unit test which is extending from StrutsSpringTestCase. When i execute actions, it is not invoking the stubbed methods, instead it is calling original methods.

Comment: Post some relevant code.

Comment: I used @Mock DependentClass mockedClass; and created Stub like when(mockedClass.method1()).thenReturn(); and invoked the action using execute() of StrutsTestCase.

Comment: Use @InjectMocks http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your action class use your mock object. Use either a setter or the `@InjectMocks` annotation to put that object into your action class.